# How Do I Display a number without it being in scientific notation in a Python calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How Do I make a number appear like this:

```
$25.23
```

Instead of this?:

```
$2.5 e+02
```

besides on how to do it, why it is being shown in scientific notation?

Also, if it matters, I am trying to make a price calculator, so I need prices to be shown as that:

```
xyz.wd
```

The current code I am using:

```
p1= float(input("Price:"))
d= float(input("discount percentage:"))
discount = p1*(d/100)
p2 = p1-discount
print(f"discount value: ${discount:10.2}")
print(f"final value: ${p2:10.2}")
```

Comment: tried specifying that it is a floating point number? e.g. `print(f"final value: ${p2:10.2f}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(f"discount value: ${discount:10.2f}")
print(f"final value: ${p2:10.2f}")
```